# Best way to add & retrieve list items using dictionary

Tags: vb.net, list, dictionary

I need to add a list of items for each user. User ID is unique and each user has multiple devices with devicename, devicetype and description.

So I created a dictionary to add list of those devices for each user's user id as key.

```
    Dim dicUserDevices As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Object()))
    If dicUserDevices.ContainsKey(userid) Then
        dicUserDevices(userid).Add(New Object() {devicename, devicetype, devicedescription})
    Else
           dicUserDevices.Add(userid, New List(Of Object()))
           dicUserDevices(userid).Add(New Object() {devicename, devicetype, devicedescription})
    End If
```

To retrieve it I do the following:

```
 Dim devices = dicUserDevices.Item(userid)
 For Each item In devices
            Dim device = {item(0), item(1), item(2)}
 Next
```

This works but I don't feel comfortable with the way I use indexes. Am I doing it wrong? Is it a bad practice? Will it give me error in some scenarios? What is the best way ?

Comment: You could create a class that encapsulates the data for each device, and use that in the List.  Then you could loop through the devices in the list for a given user with a `For Each` loop.

Comment: ...or make one of the DeviceInfo properties a collection (depends on the type of devices and how you can identify them)

Comment: Would the current code break in some scenarios? I'm assuming that since I added exactly 3 items, it shouldn't be a problem to index them 0, 1, 2 while retrieving.

Comment: Why use `List(Of Object)`?  That kind of defeats the purpose of generics.  You may as well just use `ArrayList`.  Do as OneFineDay suggests and create a class for your device and then use a `List(Of Device)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll through it out there - a class would have an `OOP` feel to it and queries are simple and intuitive.

```
Public Class DeviceInfo 
 Public Property User As String
 Public Property DeviceName As String
 Public Property DeviceType As String
 Public Property DeviceDescription As String
End Class
```

If you like the `ContainsKey` functionality then use this:

```
Public Class DeviceInfos : Inherits List(Of DeviceInfo)
  Public Function ContainsKey(user As String) As Boolean
    Return Me.Any(Function(di) di.User = user)
  End Function
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Private UserDevices As New DeviceInfos
```

Fill your object:

```
If Not UserDevices.ContainsKey(userId) Then
  Dim di As New DeviceInfo 
  di.User = userId
  di.DeviceName = devicename
  di.DeviceType = devicetype
  di.DeviceDescription = devicedescription
  UserDevices.Add(di)
End If
```

Query:

```
Dim deviceTypeQuery = From di In UserDevices Where 
                      di.DeviceType = "some type" And
                      di.User = "some user id"
```